# Rice has water inside after being cooked

Tags: rice, sticky-rice

I have this Rooster A.A.A. Scented Jasmine Rice that I recently bought and after a few days, water starts forming in the middle for some reason.

A little background, I had a bag of Thai rice that when I leave the rice cooker unplugged (and rice not kept warm), the rice becomes sticky which is what I like. Now with this new Jasmine rice, I do the same thing but instead the water forms.

Am I misinterpreting something where Jasmine rice does not have the same effect as Thai rice?

Comment: How humid is your kitchen?

Comment: Tends to be a bit humid

Comment: Wait, you're leaving the rice in the rice cooker unplugged at room temperature for a few days?

Comment: I am, but with the rice I initially used, there weren't any puddles forming, it would actually get sticky.

Comment: It's not about puddles, it's about the fact that that's unsafe. I'm glad you've been lucky enough not to get food poisoning from it yet, but cooked rice is [definitely not safe for long periods unless refrigerated](http://www.foodsafety.gov/poisoning/causes/bacteriaviruses/bcereus/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an actual pool of water forms or the rice just does not get sticky like your other rice?

Have you tried different amounts of water to cook it, either more or less?

All rice is different, depending on the variety and where it's grown. You sometimes have to treat a new rice differently than the rice you're used to.

Comment: A pool of water forms

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration. I learned by trial and error but good rice is always worth a few fails. :)

I've found that Rooster A.A.A. Scented Jasmine Rice is a sweet rice/sticky (glutinous) rice that works best when soaked in water (after cleaning the rice...so that I can soak it in the correct amount of water) at least 30 minutes before cooking and it is a sticky rice...but you are right that it is not supposed to be wet. (Note: try not to open the cooker while it is cooking; rice is very fragile. If water comes out or accumulates at the steam vent; use less water next time)

Rice cookers have different settings that measure out the soaking times (if not, adjust by soaking, using chilled water or the amount of water to control settings manually yourself). If I am cooking regular rice; I put my Zojirushi rice cooker on the "Quick Cooking" setting but if I use sticky rice like sushi rice; I use the "White Rice/Sushi Rice" setting. I also use the "white rice" setting for an average Jasmine rice or the "sushi" setting if I want it to be sticky like Korean rice (for my Kimchi). Remember to use the cups that come with your cooker for the dry measuring and use the marks on the pan for the water *after you put your rice in the pot. Be sure to rinse your rice 5 times every time for consistency.

I have seen quite a difference in textures from the different varieties that I've tried over the years. Try different settings till you get what you want. If you find that the rice is too wet or too dry; add or back off on water with very little variance. A little bit can make a big difference in an enclosed cooker.

Food for thought: Basmati rice (a longer grain of rice) will not work well in this kind of cooker since it cooks on a higher temperature; as to not fall apart. So it is good to keep the length of the grain in mind when cooking.

(Check out a Pars Cooker for Persian "Bottom of the Pot" (Tahdig/ته دیگ ) rice, Korean (Nurungji/누룽지)Burnt Rice or Japanese Scorched (Okoge/おこげ)Rice.)

*Soaking these rices greatly improves the even crisping but; soak it in the same pre-measured water (washing 5 times less intensively than other rices due to their fragile nature). Soaking for some...not for all. Always using a cloth or paper towel between the rim and the lid for Basmati is imperative while cooking in a Pars Cooker or pot to stop water from pooling.

Which makes me wonder if your cooker is getting too hot. With a Pars Cooker, you can adjust the heat to cook other rices by choosing the shorter cooking settings however; to get more browning, longer settings will progressively darken the rice.`(With regular rice, you can start the rice with chilled water to reverse extreme heat in the first cooking phase of your unit)

So, take notice of the consistency of your rice where it touches the pan (or pot) to determine if the correct temperature is being reached in your pot.

I keep specific notes for each rice on my cooker manual & always keep it in my cooker when not in use. :)

Comment: What if my rice cooker doesn't have any settings? Like my one is just a really basic one with just like the button to start cooking it and that's about it.

Comment: Also about the soaking in water for 30 minutes, is this supposed to be after washing the rice or before?

Comment: I have ammended above; addressing your questions in parentheses. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of rice you're using but it maybe because of the quantity of water you're taking to cook the rice. It might vary for different type of rice but I typically use double the volume of water as the rice taken. For ex- if I'm making One bowl full of rice I'll use Two bowl water to cook the same.